# Read body/Query parametr in wso2 esb 4.8 or 4.8.1?

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

How to read body param or query param in wso2 ESB 4.8 or 4.81.We tried with following format,

```
<property name="uri.var.name" expression="$url:name"></property>

<property name="uri.var.name" expression="$body/name"></property>
```

It succeeded with 4.7,But not working in WSO2 ESB 4.8 and 4.8.1 ..Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To read request params :

Sample request : `http://localhost:8280/services/MyService?param1=val1&param2=val2`

```
<property name="PARAM1" expression="tokenize(substring-after(syn:get-property('To'),'param1='),'&')"/>

<property name="PARAM1" expression="tokenize(substring-after(syn:get-property('To'),'param2='),'&')"/>
```

Comment: this is a http post request ? what is his contentType ? try a <log level="full"/> inside inSequence : ESB should wrap the content inside a soap envelope / body and $body should offer you a way to access body content